# onmouseover javascript opacity for IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, transparency, inline

This is what I have so far:

```
<img src="images/test.jpg" 
class="black" 

onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;
this.filters.alpha.opacity=100;
this.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"

onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.3;
this.filters.alpha.opacity=30;
this.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)'" 
/>
```

It's works in FF and Safari, but not IE 7 or 8.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh! CSS for the win!

```
<style>
img.black:hover {opacity: 0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30);}
</style>
```

Comment: Just remember that `:hover` will only work on `<a>` elements in IE6.

Comment: Note: The alpha filter will not work in IE7 unless you also set the WIDTH of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `this.filters.alpha.opacity=30` line.  Corrected code:

```
<img src="images/test.jpg" class="black"  
    onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1; 
      this.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)'" 

    onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.3
      this.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)'"  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a framework like YUI or JQuery to help you normalize cross-browser inconsistencies like this?